# R/exams to create a batch of different exercises

Tags: r-exams

I recently discovered the R/exams package and I found it very useful to create exercises that I use with moodle.

However, it is not clear to me how to use it to produce a given number of *different* exercises from a single .Rmd file. Assume that I create 4 different parameter sets to be used in 4 different exercises. Here is my data generation section:

```
{r data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
data=read.csv(header=T,text="
   r,b,g,p
   .05,1.3,.04,.03
   .04,1.2,.05,.025
   .035,1.1,.02,.03
   .025,1.25,.015,.025")
i = sample(1:nrow(data),1)
dd=data[i,]
```

This randomly assigns a row from `data` to the variable `dd`, which is used to produce the exercise. Then, by setting the argument `n` in `exams2moodle`, I can randomly generate as many exercises as I want, of 4 different types.

However, what if instead I want to have exactly 4 exercises each using a different set? Using the option `n=4` as an argument of `exams2moodle', the 4 exercises picked up at random will likely involve repetition and will not be necessarily different one from another.

Comment: @DarkBee: I see you edited my question and modified the indentation in the code.  However, the solution suggested below by @Achim Zeileis does not work when the assignment to variable `i` is indented.

Comment: By all means, remove then idents if they are troublesome, but you had the 3 back ticks for the code block next to the code which formatted your code wrong

Comment: Yes, I realized it. However, the 3 back ticks are in the original .Rmd file (this is a code block embedded in a markdown file) so I wanted to make them visible to the reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** R/exams has been mainly designed for the setup where you generate large number of different exercises where it is not necessary/easy/feasible to track every possible random variation. Hence there is no built-in infrastructure to easily generate every possible variation of an exercise. I typically do not worry that some of the many variations I generate might be identical "by chance" - as long as there is still sufficient random variation.

**Workaround:** However, there is the `expar()` function that creates temporary copies of an exercise with certain (scalar) variables fixed. See `?expar` for further details. Using this you could do:

```
expar("myexercise.Rmd", i = 1)
```

This gives you a temporary file that you can use as input for all `exams2xyz()` generators. So you can use this with `i = 1` up to `i = 4` to give you all four versions of your exercise.

**Illustration:** I'm using the [countrycodes](https://www.R-exams.org/templates/countrycodes/) exercise template shipped along with the package. This also has a finite set of variable combinations from which some `i` is sampled (in 1, ..., 167). To get the first four of these you can do:

```
ccodes <- sapply(1:4, function(ii) expar("countrycodes.Rmd", i = ii))
exams2html(ccodes, solution = FALSE)
```

---

#### Exam

1. **Question**
   What is the three-letter country code (ISO 3166-1 alpha-3) for Angola?
2. **Question**
   What is the three-letter country code (ISO 3166-1 alpha-3) for Albania?
3. **Question**
   What is the three-letter country code (ISO 3166-1 alpha-3) for Argentina?
4. **Question**
   What is the three-letter country code (ISO 3166-1 alpha-3) for Armenia?

---

Instead of using `exams2html()` you can also use `exams2moodle()` or any other `exams2xyz()` interface.

Comment: Thank you.
About the disclaimer: I understand, but, as a moodle user, I prefer to rely on moodle for randomization, drawing from a definite pool of (different) exercises.
About the solution: it works, but I had some troubles. R gave me an error `parameter 'i' not defined in first code chunk` until I aligned the command `i = sample(1:nrow(data),1)` in the code chunk to the beginning of the line.